# MySQL C++ Connector: How do I get the thread/connection Id?

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to find out how to obtain the MySQL Connection/thread id using  Connector C++.

[mysql_thread_id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-thread-id.html)(MYSQL* ) seems to be available for just this, but I'm not sure how to get an instance of MYSQL from the Connector C++.

What I've tried:

```
  int threadId = mysql_thread_id(NULL);
```

But this just returns zero.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function mysql_thread_id() expects a pointer to a connection object created by the native MySQL C API's mysql_connect(...) function. Connector/C++ has buried that object very deep (I looked). The alternative suggested by MySQL's documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-thread-id.html) is to execute query `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()` and the returned result will be the ID you're looking for.

Comment: The signature is mysql_thread_id(MYSQL*  mysql) though, so this shouldn't work(you're passing in a sql::Connection* instead of MYSQL*). I tried it out as well, and get a compilation error as expected.

Comment: Passing the connection pointer works when using the native MySQL C API, but as you said does not appear to work with Connector/C++ connection objects. One alternative would be to execute the query `SELECT CONNECTION_ID()` and retrieving the result (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-thread-id.html).

Comment: I edited my answer to show the alternative solution :)